Access denied to AWS RDS through Django on ECS
I am getting the following error in my AWS ECS Task logs:
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'[ECS Task IP]' (using password: YES)")
My goal is to connect a Django container in ECS to a MySQL database in AWS RDS. I am injecting the password through Github Actions from a Secret that I have copied from the AWS Secret Manager, which was autogenerated by RDS.
I have verified that the password and username are correct. I have also looked through other StackOverflow posts and did not see any that met my use case. If there was a post that covered this topic that I missed, I apologize.

Double-check the database hostname in your configuration.

Hostname was correct, the issue was that the autogenerated password was using disallowed characters. I provided the answer below.

Turns out the password generated by AWS Secrets Manager was using characters that weren't allowed in MySQL which led to the authentication failure. Problem solved by making the password Self-Managed and auto-generated by RDS itself. Hope this helps someone.
